# Local System account event log permissions

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, event-log

Does anybody know of a way I can check what permissions the Local System account has with the Application event log? There is no **CustomSD** at **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog\Application** so I am just wondering how to check what permissions it has by default? Any help is much appreciated!

I am using Windows Server 2008.

Comment: Pretty sure Local System would have full access.  [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363658%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) lists the default rights for 2000/XP; probably the same for more recent versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run the following command: **wevtutil gl application** the security level on the event log is described using SDDL in the channelAccess section of the output.